# Change element when submit modal using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying change text and value of element when I submit modal which opened by clicked a tag event, but I still dont know how to do it. Picture below describe my idea.

I tried delete and replace html but it doesn't work, I am still stuck.

Thank you so much.

This is my code:

```
<div class="report-filter-selector">
  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-info">
    <a
      class="openEditModalBtn"
      data-toggle="modal"
      data-field="form_name"
      data-value="request_all"
      href="#editFilterSelectorModal"
    >form name: request_all</a>&nbsp;
    <button
      class="selector-control-btn" id="selector-control-btn"
    ><i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
  <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="request_all">
</div>

<!-- edit filter selector modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editFilterSelectorModal" data-backdrop="static"
     tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editFilterSelectorModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit condition </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="add_body">
        <div class="message-content" name="error" id="add_err"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Condition:</label>
          <select name="edit_field_selector" id="edit_field_selector"
                  onchange="loadValueByCondition();" disabled>
            <option value="form_name">form_name</option>
            <option value="prefecture">prefecture</option>
            <option value="time">Time</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Value:</label>
          <div id="edit_value_by_selector" class="edit_value_by_selector"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                id="edit-filter-selector-submit"
                name="edit-filter-selector-submit">保存
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
                id="close-new-form">閉じる
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As my fault, I forgot upload Javascript code, that is my code to create element and try to change after modal edit submit.

```
//this code create <a> element like number 1 in picture 
$('#add-filter-selector-submit').click(function(e){
    
    let condition = $('#add_field_selector').val();
    let val = "example1";
    
    let html   = '<td><div class="report-filter-selector">';
        html  += '<span class="badge rounded-pill bg-info"><a class="openEditModalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-field="'+condition+'" data-value="'+val+'" href="#editFilterSelectorModal">'+condition+':'+val+'</a>&nbsp;<button class="delete-selector-control-btn" id="delete-selector-control-btn"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button></span>';
        html  += '<input type="hidden" name="'+condition+'" value="'+val+'">';
        html  += '</div></td>';

    $("#filter_conditions_table tr:first").append(html);
});

//this code try to change element when submit edit modal:
$('#edit-filter-selector-submit').click(function(e){
    // I dont know how to do next
});
```

[image]

Comment: Post your JavaScript please

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for your reply. I tried use ```$ (this) .closet('.report-filter-selector')``` to change a tag element clicked but I got my mistake, it is impossible.so I don't have any idea how to do it next.

Comment: @j08691 I've update my question with JS code. So please check it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this code with javascript.

Add function to button change:

```
function change() {
    $("#edit_field_selector2").val('1').change()
    $("#edit_field_selector").val('prefecture').change()
}
```

Comment: Sorry I think but you misunderstood my question, so I updated my question and JS code. Check it, please. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to assume that your second select is created using similar naming conventions to your first one in your example HTML. You can use the code below to

1. Select a button (replace `#edit-filter-selector-submit`") and run a function when it is clicked
2. Change the value of a `select` using `.val()` - you need to pass the value you want to switch to

---

```
// Add event listener to the button
$("#edit-filter-selector-submit").click(function() {

   // Change the value of the select item   $("#edit_value_selector").val("2");

});
```

---

```js
// Add event listener to the button
$("#edit-filter-selector-submit").click(function() {

  // Change the value of the select item
  $("#edit_value_selector").val("2");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="report-filter-selector">
  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-info">
    <a
      class="openEditModalBtn"
      data-toggle="modal"
      data-field="form_name"
      data-value="request_all"
      href="#editFilterSelectorModal"
    >form name: request_all</a>&nbsp;
    <button
      class="selector-control-btn" id="selector-control-btn"
    ><i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
  <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="request_all">
</div>

<!-- edit filter selector modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editFilterSelectorModal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editFilterSelectorModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit condition </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="add_body">
        <div class="message-content" name="error" id="add_err"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Condition:</label>
          <select name="edit_field_selector" id="edit_field_selector" onchange="loadValueByCondition();" disabled>
            <option value="form_name">form_name</option>
            <option value="prefecture">prefecture</option>
            <option value="time">Time</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Value:</label>
          <div id="edit_value_by_selector" class="edit_value_by_selector">
          <select name="edit_value_selector" id="edit_value_selector" onchange="loadValueByCondition();" disabled>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="edit-filter-selector-submit" name="edit-filter-selector-submit">Change
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="close-new-form">Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad question made you misunderstood my idea. I've updated my question and JS code, check it again.Please suggest me any idea to do it. thank you.